# PHP/SQL error which executing

Tags: php, sql, pdo

```
<?php
$dbhost="host";
$dbusername="user";
$dbpassword="pass";
$dbname="db";

try {
  # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
  echo "Connected Successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

#  close the connection  
$DBH = null; 
?>
```

When running it in my server, i get the following error:

```
Parse error: parse error, unexpected '{' in /home/web/i/htdocs/search/pdo.php on line 7
```

I am trying to do a test to use PDO to save variable to a database and was advised PDO was the way to securely store variable to a database. Please let me know why I am receiving the error and how to resolve it.

Comment: Is this the full code your running on a separate PHP file - no other includes?

Comment: http://www.interfaithmedical.com/search/pdo.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run your code and do not get a parse error. It looks all fine.
Maybe you did not run the same as you posted here.

Comment: I checked the PHP parser and everything is fine. Maybe it's the web server?

Comment: Is this now resolved as you have marked it as answered yet continue to post.